# Know the gridview row height in asp.net code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` and using `DataSet` to `Bind` that. And `Gridview` `Height` set to autoHeight;

Suppose I have 3 rows in My `GridView`, After bind I want to fetch the row height of each row.

I know that I can set the `RowHeight` dynamically by

```
GridView1.RowStyle.Height = 40;
```

But I want somthing like my be

```
int height=GridView1.Rows[0].Height;
```

I can manage my logic of the above code using `for` or any.....

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a `foreach` loop, then you can use a `RowDataBound` event to find the height of each row.

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        ViewState["rowHeightList"] = new List<decimal>();
    }
}
```

```cs
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
    decimal currentRowHeight = Convert.ToDecimal(e.Row.Height);

    List<decimal> rowHeightList = (List<decimal>)ViewState["rowHeightList"];
    rowHeightList.Add(currentRowHeight);

    ViewState["rowHeightList"] = rowHeightList;
}
```

Comment: i think the alert wont work, but if you assing it to an array or a list it should work